# How to fix invalid unicode characters(?) in fedora 23?

Tags: terminal, character, zsh, oh-my-zsh, fedora-23

I install [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) & [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

I use the [lambda-mod-zsh-theme](https://github.com/halfo/lambda-mod-zsh-theme). I copy `lambda-mod.zsh-theme` file to the `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/lambda-mod` directory and edit file `~/.zshrc` with `ZSH_THEME="lambda-mod/lambda-mod"`

In terminal ([terminator](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/terminator)) I see the next artifact

[image: invalid character]

In terminator settings default encoding set as Unicode UTF-8.

It's my locale:

```
$locale     
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How I can fix it?

Fedora 23 KDE 64bit

Answer (score -1):

solution in [this issue](https://github.com/halfo/lambda-mod-zsh-theme/issues/1).

Just need to install [this fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) (powerline/fonts) and select font in terminal settings